# Limit archive widget results

Tags: widgets, archives

Is there a way to limit the amount of months shown in the Archive widget? I don't want to use a drop-down list (I can manually add a drop down in my footer so people can get the full archive). I'm currently showing 19 months in my Archive list, and want to limit it to 7. I know you can do this manually, but that would mess up my theme, so I wanted to do this with the Archive widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) from [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) and then simply put this in the widget to limit the archives to 7 months:

`<ul><?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=7'); ?></ul>`

(Give the widget a title like Archives if you want, and remove the default WordPress Archive widget.)

[Function Reference/wp get archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)